# How does one use pattern matching to check if something is even in OCAML?

Tags: ocaml

I tried:

```
let rec f n =
match n with
| 0 -> case0
| k -> case1
| (2*k) -> case2;;
```

but didn’t work…

---

https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/how-does-one-us-pattern-matching-to-check-if-something-is-even/4366
https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-does-one-use-pattern-matching-to-check-if-something-is-even

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is structural in OCaml. So the following code will check if the structure of the value you match is the same as `k`, which is always the case, and then the value is bound to `k`. So anything not already matching `0` matches `k`. Any variables in a match are always bound, never compared to an existing binding.

```
| k -> case1
```

Next you have the following but `2*k` is not any structure of a value. It's an expression or it would be a type if you ignore that `2` is an integer literal.

```
| (2*k) -> case2
```

If you want to match the value of something you have to use `when` like

```
match n with
| x when x mod 2 = 0 -> even
| _ -> odd
```

A better match would be to simply match `n % 2` against 0 and 1. Or, since this is a match with exactly 2 cases simply use

```
if n mod 2 = 0 then even
else odd
```